# What is the meaning of "Son of a gun"

Tags: idioms

I've just been faced with the statement "**Son of a gun**" in a film, and i don't know the meaning of it.

I think it must be an idiom, but i did not find anything when i searched for it in the google.

Comment: It's really "[son of a gun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Son_of_a_gun)", an euphemism for "*son of a bitch*".

Comment: There's a really good answer to this over on ELU http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37211/origin-of-son-of-a-gun (not sure whether or not that counts as a dupe - I'll leave that call to someone else)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @CopperKettle points out it's actually ***son*** of a gun.

> The phrase potentially has its origin in a Royal Navy requirement that
>   pregnant women aboard naval vessels give birth in the space between
>   the broadside guns, in order to keep the gangways and crew decks
>   clear. Admiral William Henry Smyth wrote in his 1867 book, The
>   Sailor's Word-Book: "Son of a gun, an epithet conveying contempt in a
>   slight degree, and originally applied to boys born afloat, when women
>   were permitted to accompany their husbands to sea; one admiral
>   declared he literally was thus cradled, under the breast of a
>   gun-carriage." - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Son_of_a_gun)

Comment: It's important to realize that even though this is the origin of the phrase, very few people (if any) will think of this when they hear the phrase. It's really used as a euphemism for "son of a bitch".

Comment: That's actually covered by Admiral William Henry Smyth himself: "Son of a gun, an epithet conveying contempt in a slight degree". It's not so much a stand-in for it, they're just similar phrases with similar contexts. i.e. you're a [son] born of [a method I find distasteful].